# Converting R1C1 format to A1 format

Tags: c

In an excel spreadsheet we have each cell denoted by its row and column either in R1C1 format or the A1 format.

R1C1 format indicates the row number and the column number. For example, R23C55 means row 23 and column 55.

In the A1 format, each column is given a code, based on alphabet permutatons. Consider the first 26 columns, each are named from A to Z. The next column (i.e 27th column) would be AA, and AB,AC and so on. For example, BC23 would mean column BC which is the 55th column and row 23 which is ofcourse the 23rd row.

I need to convert an input of the form R1C1 to an output of the form A1. For example, R23C55 would be BC23 where BC is the corresponding output for 55.

I have made a code to convert a given column number to its A1 format.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int column,temp,i=0;
    char col[5];

    scanf("%d",&column);
    temp=column;

    while(temp!=0)
    {
        if(temp%26==0)
            {
                col[i]='Z';
                i++;
        }
        else
        {
            col[i]=(temp%26)-1+'A';
            i++;
        }
        temp=(temp-1)/26;
    }
    col[i]='\0';
    strrev(col);
    puts(col);

    return 0;
}
```

I can convert an input number 55 to its output BC. But I cannot proceed with a code for converting R23C55 to BC23. How do I take the input R23C55, extract numbers 23 and 55, and give output of the form BC23?

Comment: I think you will need to give a little more details.

Comment: I don't understand what'are the rules of the conversion you indicate! Can you give more info?

Comment: @SergioFormiggini: think Excel. R1C1 = numeric, 1-based indexes for rows and columns; A1 = one or two letters for columns (A->Z, AA-AZ, BA->BZ ..., ZA->ZZ), 1-based index for rows.

Comment: Assuming r1c1 is  row1 column 1, and you want  to convert to an MS Excel notation of A1???  Is this what you are after?

Comment: @ryyker I want to input a number of format R1C1 and convert it to A1 format. My code only converts any column number input to alphabetical format.

Comment: So basically, you want to take the number part of "CNN", and convert it to a base-26 number using letters as digits...

Comment: @twalberg.: Yeah! twalberg, thats the idea. I have implemented using that idea.

Comment: It seems simple!!! :p ... But is not a normal base 26 conversion!!!

Comment: Using base 26, we consider the first row (row 1) as value 0, then we have A = 0, B = 1 ... Z = 25 ... the row of value 26 (the 27th) will have code BA (26*1+1*0) ... but we want AA!

Comment: ... Furthermore, using base 26, we have that A, AA, AAA, AAAA is always 0!!!

Comment: @SergioFormiggini Using a 1-based alphabet (A = 1, B = 2, ...) partially resolves that issue. Most spreadsheets don't number rows/columns starting at 0, anyway. That exposes a valid point, though, that the conversion to "base-26" isn't quite as straightforward without a zero element...

Comment: @twalberg: We have to look better the code!!! There's always a reply in the code of the question!!! The answer was another!!! :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include<cstdio>
void g(int t){if(t){g((t-1)/26);putchar(65+(t-1)%26);}}
int main(){
  int n,x,y;
  char s[64];
  
    fgets(s,64,stdin);
    if(sscanf(s,"R%dC%d",&x,&y)==2){
      g(y);
      printf("%d\n",x);
    
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This program precisely does what you want. The logic is clear from the code.

> Check this link to learn about `sscanf()`  [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/)
>
> Here for your use scanf("R%dC%d",..) will also work. But I have used sscanf() to provide you with a way that will be helpful if further some processing is required.

Say the input format is

```
4
R23C45
R24C55
R2C4
R12C45
```

then you could take them this way-

```
fgets(s,64,stdin);
sscanf(s,"%d",&n);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{   fgets(s,64,stdin);
   ...
}
```

Comment: it is working.. trying to understand what sscanf does

Comment: `gets()` is no longer available since C11 as a standard function.

Comment: @chux.: Yes that's right..but I have just answered the questions using the simple functions. Later I also mentioned that using the `scanf` also this can be solved. I just got in my mind the code,and posted it. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: 1) Using `gets()` detracts from this answer as it suggests using an unavailable function (C11) or depreciation function (C99) is somehow OK.  2) Using a space in `scanf("%d ",&n)` is a problem as it typically obliges the user to enter non-white-space data after the number before `scanf()` returns.  Consider replacing `scanf("%d ",&n);... gets(s);` with one `fgets()`.

Comment: @chux.: Check my answer now. Hope it is now better than before.

Comment: @chux.:honestly, the questions algorithmic part was attractive. I quickly implemented it. Sorry! if there was some mistake.

Comment: @AtulShanbhag.: Maybe you can do this for multiline inputs.check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could simply parse the `RxCy` string with `scanf` :

```
int main()
{
    int column, row, cr,temp,i=0;
    char col[5];

    cr = scanf("R%dC%d",&row, &column);
    /* if cr == 2, row and column containing the coordinates */
   ...
```

Comment: that is exactly what i am not sure of

Comment: could you explain what is cr==2?

Comment: That's the reason why I advise you to test the return of `scanf`. It works.... provided input has correct format (even if it will accept inputs containing spaces like `R 1C 12`)

Comment: You're welcome. But you should mark an answer as accepted to notify that you no longer need help with this question.

Comment: @AtulShanbhag: `scanf` and related like `fscanf` and `sscanf` return the number of arguments successfully converted. It is really good practice to always test that do deal properly with badly formatted inputs.

Comment: sir what do i do if i need multiple inputs?